# How to dynamically add class in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-dom

In simple tic-tac game,When someone wins, highlight the three squares that caused the win.

```html
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="PQyERJ" data-default-tab="js,result" data-user="akshgods" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Simple tic tac game" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/akshgods/pen/PQyERJ/">Simple tic tac game</a> by ganesh (<a href="https://codepen.io/akshgods">@akshgods</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
<script async src="https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

In this pen , you can see in console if you win, the winning indexes are logged. can some one update the code, and explain it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit - Jan 2019:**

You can also use the `classnames` package to do that. The package can be found [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) and is used like this:

```
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); -> The result classes will be 'foo bar'.
classNames('foo', { bar: false }); -> The result class will be just 'foo'.
```

---

As I didn't understand your question I will answer the question you wrote on the title.

In order to dynamically add class to and element in react you can use the [Template Strings](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#template-strings) functionality in ES2015.

It should look like this:

```
<div className={`main-class ${this.state.isSelected ? 'selected':''}`}></div>
```

And then the selected class will be added once the state is changed.

Comment: @GaneshGodshelwar if you found this answer helpful please mark it as an answer for later on searches.