# How to add class to clicked element only in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have dynamic menu items created from api. I'm calling class change function onClick but class is adding to all menus. I need add class to only clicked element not to whole menu list below is my code.

```
 {menuSideBar.map(menu => (
            <ListItem
              className={SideMenuClass.join(" ")}
              onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this)}
              button
            >
              <ListItemIcon className="sidebar_menu_icons">
                <SendIcon />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <Link className="sidebar_menu_links"  to={menu.url != "" ? "/" + menu.url : "#"}>
                <ListItemText inset primary={menu.resourceValue} />
              </Link>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
```

Below is function

```
  toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState({ addClass: !this.state.addClass });
  };

  let SideMenuClass = ["sidebar_menu_list"];
    if (this.state.addClass) {
    SideMenuClass.push("selected_sidebar_menu");
 }
```

Please help how can I add class to only clicked element?

Thank you.

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989828/how-to-dynamically-add-class-in-react

Comment: But you can use `e.target.classList.add()` into toggleClass

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina that is bad

Comment: @fard, any link or resources?

Comment: @Michael I need to add class onclick

Comment: better use arror functions instead of bind. and don´t use classlist in react. do stuff with the state, don´t interact with the DOM directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can save id's of selected items as array in state

```
{menuSideBar.map(menu => (
<Item
  className={this.state.ids.includes(menu.id) ? 'active' : ''} 
  onClick={() => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      ids: oldState.ids.includes(menu.id) ? oldState.ids.filter(x => x !== menu.id) : [...oldState.ids, menu.id]
    }));
  }} 
  button
/>
))}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/4wv6n31q90?fontsize=14

---

Or if you need only last one selected:

```
{menuSideBar.map(menu => (
<Item
  className={this.state.lastClicked === menu.id ? 'active' : ''} 
  onClick={() => {
    this.setState({lastClicled: menu.id});
  }} 
  button
/>
))}
```

Comment: It giving includes undefined

Comment: @SagarKodte be sure to initialize `ids` as `[]` in state

Comment: after clicking on menu TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

Comment: @SagarKodte i've updated, there was typo - `[...oldState.ids, menu.id]` instead of `[...oldState, menu.id]`

Comment: Added same thing is happening. Class is adding to all menus

Comment: Ok let me check & also It will remove from another menu after clicking anonther menu..basically it's active menu functionality

Answer (score 0):

Store menu item id in the state - then in render (`map`) check if equals to current element - adjust classes acordingly (apply class for selected only).