# Have transparent bootstrap navbar, would like navbar to stay transparent but for the menu that appears after you click the hamburger to be colored

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap, transparent

I am a very Junior developer, I am making a website in ReactJS, I have a bootstrap Navbar set to Transparent at the top of the page, when you scroll it changes to have color. I would like it if when you click the "hamburger" if the menu items had a background color other than transparent. I have a full screen image that the transparent navbar sits on top ofand the menu isn't really visible without a background color...Thanks for your help.

JSX.....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from "jquery"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown  } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import './transnav.css';


export default class TransNavigationBar extends Component {

componentDidMount() {

(document).ready(function() {

(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

     //>=, not <=
    if (scroll >= 610) {
        //clearHeader, not clearheader - caps H
        $(".navbar").addClass("test1");
        $(".navbar-brand").removeClass("test");
        $(".navbar-brand").addClass("text-white");

    } else {
      $(".navbar").removeClass("test1");
      $(".navbar-brand").removeClass("text-white");
      $(".navbar-brand").addClass("test");
    }
}); 
  
});
}
    render() {
        return (
<div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top ">
   
    <Navbar expand="lg" bg="" variant='light'>
    <a class="navbar-brand test" href="#">Cincinnati Lifestyle</a>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav "/>
                    <Navbar.Collapse id=" mr-auto basic-navbar-nav ">
                        <Nav className="ml-auto ">                                                   
                        <Nav.Item >
                            <Nav.Link>
                            <Link className="text-white" to="/">Home</Link>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item >
                        <NavDropdown title={ <span className="text-white">Attractions</span>} id="basic-nav-dropdown" >
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="/viewattractions">View Attraction</NavDropdown.Item>
                                <NavDropdown.Item href="/addattractions">Add Attractions</NavDropdown.Item>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        <Nav.Item>
                            <Nav.Link>
                            <Link className="text-white" to="/about">About</Link>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item>
                            <Nav.Link>
                            <Link className="text-white" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
            </nav>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

CSS....

```
.navbar {
 width: 100%; 
}

.test{
    color: transparent !important;
    }

.test1{
    background-color: rgb(79, 106, 126) !important;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989828/how-to-dynamically-add-class-in-react

Comment: This may give you some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need jQuery for this requirement. In fact, it is recommended you avoid mutating the DOM directly when using React.

You could have states that track if the header should have color and you could switch your Navbar to be a Controlled Component so that you can control that once it is expanded, you can opt to have the menu items colored as well

```
state = {
    headerBreakPoint: 610,
    activeHeader: false,
    navbarExpanded: false
};
```

Similar to what you did on jQuery, you can add the event listeners when your component mounts.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;

    if (scrollY >= this.state.headerBreakPoint) {
      this.setState({
        activeHeader: true
      });
    } else if (
      scrollY < this.state.headerBreakPoint &&
      this.state.navbarExpanded === false
    ) {
      this.setState({
        activeHeader: false
      });
    }
  });
}
```

On the Navbar `onToggle` prop, you can have some logic to assess whether it should be colored or not

```
<Navbar
  expand="lg"
  bg=""
  variant="light"
  expanded={this.state.navbarExpanded}
  onToggle={(expanded) => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;

    const shouldHeaderBeActive = ((_) => {
      if (expanded === true) {
        return true;
      } else if (
        expanded === false &&
        scrollY < this.state.headerBreakPoint
      ) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    })();

    this.setState({
      navbarExpanded: expanded,
      activeHeader: shouldHeaderBeActive
    });
  }}
></Navbar>
```

Finally, have some conditions on your `JSX` `className` prop that will add/remove classes based on the current state

```
<nav
  className={`navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top ${this.state.activeHeader ? "test1" : ""}`}
>

<a
  className={`navbar-brand ${this.state.activeHeader ? "text-white" : "test"}`}
  href="#1"
>
  Cincinnati Lifestyle
</a>
```

[image: Edit nice-lamarr-8scyw]